# Following selenium code contain xpath error but it is giving syntax error and no output, can it be resolved?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Continuous syntax error and no output in my web scraping program. My xpath is correct as it is pointing to the correct names but I am not getting any output. The website is https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/search/?query=chair&pageNumber=1 . Can someone help?

I have python 3.4.4 and I am using visual studio code as a GUI. I am trying to get the item names from the IKEA website as a web scraping code. But I am continuously having the error. Can someone help?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, WebDriverException
import csv
import os

driver= webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python34/Scripts/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/search/?query=chair&pageNumber=1")
title =driver.findElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='prodName prodNameTro']")).text()
print(title)
```

Expected Output:

```
RENBERGET
HÄRÖ / FEJAN
ÄPPLARÖ
TÄRENDÖ / ADDE
AGAM
ÄPPLARÖ
```

These are the names of the item on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape the page with python you don't need Selenium. Much faster and easier is to use, for example, [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) and [beautifulsoap](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoap)
Here is basic example code for search chairs on [ikea](https://ikea.sa), you'll get all chairs(723) from all pages in seconds:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# array of all items
result = []

# request first page of query. "query=chair&pageNumber=1"
response = requests.get('https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/search/?query=chair&pageNumber=1')
# assert for response is OK
assert response.ok

# parse response test using html.parser
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# get last page number and convert to integer.
last_page_number = int(page.select_one(".pagination a:last-child").text)

# iterate throw from 1 to 30 pages
for i in range(1, last_page_number + 1):
    # if i==1 skip request again, because we already get response for the first page
    if i > 1:
        # request using i as parameter
        response = requests.get(f'https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/search/?query=chair&pageNumber={str(i)}')
        assert response.ok
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # get all products containers, that contains name, price and description
    products = page.select("#productsTable .parentContainer")

    # iterate throw all products in the page. get name, price and description and add to result as map
    for product in products:
        name = product.select_one(".prodName").text.strip()
        desc = product.select_one(".prodDesc").text.strip()
        price = product.select_one(".prodPrice,.prodNlpTroPrice").text.strip()
        result.append({"name": name, "desc": desc, "price": price})

# print results, you can do anything..
for r in result:
    print(f"name: {r['name']}, price: {r['price']}, description: {r['desc']}")

print("the end")
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you are the best (Y)

Comment: In line **products = page.select("#productsTable .parentContainer")** and **last_page_number = int(page.select_one(".pagination a:last-child").text)**, what does _"#productsTable "_ and _".pagination a:last-child"_ means?

Comment: Open chrome devtools elements tab, press ctrl+f to search and enter `#productsTable .parentContainer`, you'll see products divs. Same for `.pagination a:last-child`, it gets last page number in pagination.

Comment: I want to learn this amazing code of yours and I hope that you can help me with that: the html  is ** div class="parentContainer" ** and ** div id="productsTable" class="productsContainer" ** so how have you merged it as _"#productsTable .parentContainer"_ and like wise for the html code ** div class="pagination" ** and **a:last-child** as _.pagination a:last-child_ . Is there some trick to do that?

Comment: There is no any trick, it's basic css selector. You can check it and make some practice: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. Also you need learn how to use xpath. This is basics and mast in test or scrape

Comment: If we want to add the link of the images as well then how the code must be amended?

Comment: find `img` tag and get `src`attribute

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple products present on the page, you can store all the values in a list and then print those values.
You can perform it like:

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python34/Scripts/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/search/?query=chair&pageNumber=1")
productNames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id,'txtNameProduct')]")
for product in productNames:
    print (product.text)
```

Comment: It is giving the following errors **Instance of 'WebDriver' has no 'findElements' member** and **Class 'By' has no 'XPath' member**.. :(

Comment: @HassanSultan i have updated my answer, please check the now

Comment: Now it is giving the following error **(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape (<unknown>, line 16)**